# Find all my github repositories that are forks

Tags: github

I have a lot of repositories on our github account.

I would like to easily find and track repositories that were originally forked, to avoid drifting and remember to send PRs upstream on a regular basis.

Is there a way to track only the repositories that were forked from other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to [Github.com](http://github.com) **logged in** or directly to **your profile-page**:

http://github.com/raphink?tab=repositories

**On both these pages there are filter-buttons for "Forks".**

Answer (score 4):

To find [all your forked repositories](https://github.com/search?q=%40raphink+fork%3Aonly&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) you can use the search option `@raphink` to get only your repositories together with `fork:only` to find forks only, i.e. search for

```
@raphink fork:only
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest using the API, but this is much simpler